# Protect redirected file from hotlinking

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, hotlinking

I have a link to download a file, similar to:

```
http://example.com/download/file.zip
```

The file is forwarded to a php script using an `.htaccess` rule. The script does download counting, and then redirects to the actual file:

```
http://example.com/download/the_real_file/file.zip
```

I have no problem with other websites linking to `download/file.zip`, but the issue is that some websites link to `download/the_real_file/file.zip` directly, thus breaking the statistics, as the script doesn't do the download counting.

I want to prevent direct linking to `download/the_real_file/file.zip`.

I tried to do that with an `.htaccess` rule:

```
# don't allow sites to link to download/the_real_file/file.zip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^download/the_real_file/file\.zip$ / [R,L]
```

This approach works, but it blocks linking to `download/file.zip` as well, as the original referrer is passed to `download/the_real_file/file.zip`, too.

Comment: The solution my team come so far is blocking all request for the file who are not from "localhost", so you need to pass from my php download page.

Comment: I don't think I understand. The php script doesn't fetch the file (`readfile` etc.), it does a redirection (header('Location: ...')).